# Multiple WHERE clauses in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My code was working fine until I added another where clause, `T.TokenType = facebook`.

Can we have as many where clauses as we want?

Or did I mess it up elsewhere.

FYI, I have facebookID of a member and want to get his/her **facebook** access token and **system** memberID.

```
SQL = "SELECT M.MemberID, M.FacebookID, T.MemberID, T.TokenType, T.Token_Code"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM MEMBERS M, TOKENS T"
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE M.FacebookID = "& strUserID &" AND M.MemberID = T.MemberID AND T.TokenType = facebook"
    Set objMember = objConn.Execute(SQL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`facebook` seems to be a string, so I'd say you're missing quotes, try changing `T.TokenType = facebook` with `T.TokenType = 'facebook'`. And yes you can have as many conditions as you want...

Comment: Hmm I didnt see that one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that instead of

```
T.TokenType = facebook
```

You want

```
T.TokenType = 'facebook'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

you need to encapsulate string values in quotes, ie `T.TokenType = "facebook"`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `facebook` isn't a column name. Try adding quotes:

```
AND T.TokenType = 'facebook'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error? Normal sql will allow as many clauses as you wish so adding another shouldn't matter. Also, is token a String? If so it needs quotes.